# Resizing tabs individually and programmatically in C# with Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, resize, tabcontrol

I have a form with a tab control.

I want each tab to have its own interface with its own size, so that I can have button layouts as necessary.

I am, in this example, only altering height.

Currently I have the default form height and default tab height set (set by tab index 0).

I need a programmatic way to set each tab's height individually, and on event `selectedIndexChanged`, I am able to resize the form as needed relative to the currently selected tab, but I don't know how to change each tab's height individually.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Inherit a class from `TabControl` and draw it yourself, or at least gain control of the height.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean by this. Maybe I should have mentioned that I'm new to C# and some of the keywords you're using, I'm not familiar with yet.

Comment: Seems to me I recall that `TabControl` doesn't want to let you set the height arbitrarily.  Meaning that you would have to create a class that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.TabControl` and in there, you would either override the height property and take control over it (not sure that would do everything you would want), or override the entire drawing of the tabs.  This will not be trivial.

Comment: That's just not possible.  The visual appearance would resemble a case of buck-teeth, very ugly.  Arranging multiple tabs in rows couldn't work either.  Not supported, all tabs must have the same height.

Comment: Alright. Well, I'm glad I know now this now. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking more about the height of the form based on the selected tab than the height of each individual tab item.

Assuming the TabControl is Dock-Filled on a parent form, you can try this code to resize the form's height based on the content of the TabPage:

```
void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var controls = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>();
  if (controls.Any()) {
    this.Height = controls.Max(x => x.Bottom) + 72;
  }
}
```

The routine finds the lowest based control on the TabPage and then adds a fudge number of 72 to account for the height of the form's non-client area and other miscellaneous spacing issues.

But note, constantly changing the height of the form based on a tab selection can be a bit jarring to the end user, and is probably not considered a popular UX implementation.

Comment: I remember this. I got the form to the point of adjusting to the lowest control's height, with a constant off-set. The next step was to make each tab have individual sizes so that it could change as different pages changed. I've abandoned this endeavor as, you're right, this wouldn't work very well when implemented.